# C Weird & interesting program output

Tags: c, memory

I've written the following code in C:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define LEN 100 

 int main(void) 
 {
    int arr[LEN];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
       printf("%d ", arr[LEN]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

First, notice I'm deliberately accessing memory which isn't part of the array (the last cell will be in index `LEN-1` and I'm accessing `arr[LEN]`, not `arr[i]`.

The weird result is that when I run the program, it prints all the numbers between 0 to... LEN-1.
For exmaple, when LEN defined to be 100 like here, the output is:

0 1 2 ..... 99

Please run the program. Does it happens to you too? I think this is platform-dependant behavior. (If it is relevant, I ran this code on Windows 7.)

Why does the value of arr[LEN] change?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. In this particular case it looks like you have optimisation disabled and `i` happens to be located at the next address after the end of `arr`, but in general literally *anything* could happen (demons, noses, etc) and it wouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: First Initialize array, Second `arr[LEN]`  is undefined behavior it should be `arr[i]`

Comment: @PaulR oh, now I get it. Thanks, that's obviously the answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It shouldn't be arr[i], I deed it by purpse. Next time read what I'm writing before commenting.

Comment: My guess is that you define `i` directly after your array. So &arr[LEN] (i.e. arr[100]) might, by chance, be the address of `i`.

Comment: Why all the down votes? Just because it is undefined doesn't mean it isn't worth wondering why that's the result.

Comment: @JeremyWest I think people assumed arr[LEN] was a mistake and should be arr[i], then downvoted to say "it's not weird platform-specific behavior that you wrote the wrong code". I've edited the question to make it clear this is deliberate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the answers of others, consider the following:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 100 

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    int arr[LEN];

    printf("&arr[LEN]: %p\n", &arr[LEN]);
    printf("&i:        %p\n", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
&arr[LEN]: 0x7fff5cf90a74  
&i:        0x7fff5cf90a74
```

On my machine, if `i` is declared before `arr`, `i` and `arr[LEN]` have the same address.

**Run the following on your machine**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 100 

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[LEN];
    int i;

    printf("&arr[LEN]: %p\n", &arr[LEN]);
    printf("&i:        %p\n", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

You should see something very similar (addresses different, of course) to what I saw.

Comment: Thanks, thats obviously the answer.

Comment: Re: "You should see something very similar" -- note that you'll need to compile with all optimisations disabled to have any chance of seeing a similar result, and even then it's by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @PaulR He already has it configured is such a way as to see something similar, hence, the question.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: I was thinking more of future readers of this answer, who might get very different results.

Comment: @PaulR You're absolutely right.  I should have kept that in mind.

Answer (score 7):

The stack is where local variables are kept. Your compiler is using the memory location after the array (`arr[LEN]` basically) to keep `i`. Therefore you are accidentally printing out `i` on each iteration. A different compiler might keep `i` somewhere else and you wouldn't see the same thing.